# One Parameter Value is Updated Literally But Others Works Fine C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

I working on insert statement where 3 values need to inserted from grabbing data from gridview and saving it in the table but "Keyword Parameter Value is getting updating literally like @Keyword in Database" but other values getting fine.

Below is the Code

```
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PositionsTable (Id,Keyword,Position) VALUES (@Id,'@Keyword',@Position)", con))
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keyword", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", SqlDbType.Int);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string keywordCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Keywords"].Value.ToString();
                    int positionCell = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Position"].Value);

                    com.Parameters["@Keyword"].Value = keywordCell;
                    com.Parameters["@Position"].Value = positionCell;
                    com.Parameters["@Id"].Value = count;
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

I was tested on debugging that keywordCell variable successfully obtains the value from gridview like the positionCell but it's gets update "@Keyword" in Database Where positionCell updated correctly.

Can you please point where I have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'@Keyword'` in VALUES(...) is wrong.

```
INSERT INTO PositionsTable (Id,Keyword,Position) VALUES (@Id, @Keyword, @Position)"
```

Answer (score 3):

you have quotes round Keyword in the SQL statement

change

```
"INSERT INTO PositionsTable (Id,Keyword,Position) VALUES (@Id,'@Keyword',@Position)"
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO PositionsTable (Id,Keyword,Position) VALUES (@Id,@Keyword,@Position)"
```

Comment: @ will accept the answer soon can't please I missed out that one :(